# Reduce file size of PDF/EPS from Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cs6

I'm trying to export a logo I created into PDF and EPS for a client and the file sizes are HUGE! The PDF is 78MB!

The logo has lots of little diamonds on it which I duplicated, so I'm guessing it's all those little elements making it that huge.

Normally when I do a logo the file sizes are pretty small, as opposed to if it were a bitmap/raster file. Needless to say this is *not* going to work out, I need to know how to flatten some layers or do *something* to make the file sizes more manageable.

I can't e-mail the client the vector files of the final product. The `.AI` file isn't even that huge, how can I minimize the file size of this project?

Answer (score 2):

Upload it to a file sharing site such as [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) and send your client a link to download it via email.

PDF is a highly useful compression format, but you won't be able to compress vectors any more than they've already been compressed by the PDF.

If, on the other hand, you can identify any parts of the vectors that can be simplified, or weren't created optimally - i.e extra unnecessary paths/anchor points - then optimising your vectors could help to reduce the file size.